# "Switch/case" statement executes all possible statements in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

I have implemented a second switch case statement into my code but for some reason one works and the other doesn't.

The broken one in question is this:

```
def graph_add_depend(caseSelected, graph, data):
switcher = {
    1: graph.addFullNC(data[1], data[0]),
    2: graph.addFullNC(data[0], data[1]),
    0: graph.addFullNC2(data[0], data[1])
}.get(caseSelected, print("Something went wrong: GAD 44"))
```

I am calling it with:

```
graph_add_depend(is_added, graph, temp)
```

When i execude the code it wont go to the correct case but will execute every one of them: aka 1 then 2 then 0

Is there anyway to fix this. I cant by the love of god find the problem.
The most frustrating thing to me is that by my eye the switch statement that works and this broken one are virtualy the same...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: Remember: _all_ expression in Python are _eagerly evaluated_ (save for RHS in short-circuiting). This includes values used in dictionaries.

Comment: Why even write code like this when the value part of the key/value is non-trivial (a unique function call)?

Comment: This is not a switch/case statement. There is no switch/case in python. You are constructing a dictionary.

Comment: @jarmod I dont know exactly what you mean but its calling a method from a class,

Comment: @zvone yea i know its an alternative, im still scratching my head why isnt it implemented though

Comment: This might be the thing you are looking for. 
https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the function to be called unless it matches the case, don't call it when you build the dictionary.  Wrapping each case in a `lambda` is a pretty easy way to delay that evaluation:

```
def graph_add_depend(caseSelected, graph, data):
    return {
        1: lambda: graph.addFullNC(data[1], data[0]),
        2: lambda: graph.addFullNC(data[0], data[1]),
        0: lambda: graph.addFullNC2(data[0], data[1])
    }[caseSelected]()
```

Note that this will automatically raise a `KeyError` if `caseSelected` is not a valid option; raising an exception is generally a better option than printing a message and returning nothing.

Comment: Yea, playing around with it for a bit, adding `lambda:` and replacing `.get(caseSelected, print("Something went wrong: GAD 44"))` with `[caseSelected]()` seemd to do the trick. Bolth were needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can simulate a switch statement using this function definition:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

Using it will give you code that a lot more legible:

```
for case in switch(caseSelected):

    if case(1):
        graph.addFullNC(data[1], data[0])
        break

    if case(2):
        graph.addFullNC(data[0], data[1])
        break

    if case(0): 
        graph.addFullNC2(data[0], data[1])
        break
else:
    print("Something went wrong: GAD 44"))
```

you can also use it with if/elif/else patterns without the breaks:

```
for case in switch(caseSelected):

    if   case(1):
         graph.addFullNC(data[1], data[0])

    elif case(2):
         graph.addFullNC(data[0], data[1])

    elif case(0): 
         graph.addFullNC2(data[0], data[1])

    else:
         print("Something went wrong: GAD 44"))
```